# right-click backup option for Windows

Tags: windows, registry

I'm trying to create a right-click option for backing up folders (and sub-folders).  I have a folder like this:

```
Folder1
  Folder1a
  Folder1b
```

I'd like to be able to right click on Folder1a, and select "Generate backup" which will create a backup of Folder1a, like so:

```
Folder1
  Folder1a
  Folder1a Copy
  Folder1b
```

I have the following command line, which does it nicely:

```
XCOPY "%1" "%1 Copy" /Y/S/E/H/K/I
```

which works nicely.

Now I just need to add it to the context menu in Windows.  When I edit the registry, adding

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Gen Backup\Command
```

and define the Command to be

```
XCOPY "%1" "%1 Copy" /Y/S/E/H/K/I
```

it doesn't work on folders, only files.  Also, it doesn't work on files either - it pops up a shell for a split second, but it doesn't create a backup of the file.

Comment: `*` is for files, not directories. If you want directories, [use `Directory`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/02/4179107.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start it in a new command shell.

Change your command to

```
cmd /c xcopy "%1%" "%1 Copy" /Y/S/E/H/K/I
```

`cmd` starts the command shell (cmd.exe), and the `/c` switch tells it to run the command and then terminate.

For more info on the command shell (cmd.exe) and it's parameters, open a command window (pun intended) and type `cmd /?` or `help cmd`.

Comment: Ken and Raymond together define the solution perfectly.  Thanks, guys!